# Locale Date Angular 8 unable to convert

Tags: angular, angular8, locale, date-pipe

In my app.module.ts I added this code:

```js
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';

import it from '@angular/common/locales/it';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';

registerLocaleData(it);
//inside here I got all the necessary imports that I will not write here to avoid confusion
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "it-IT" }],
  bootstrap: []
})
```

Inside my html I have

```html
<dd *ngIf="rec.DATECREATE" class="col-sm-8">{{rec.DATECREATE | date:'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'}}</dd>
```

I get this error

> Error: InvalidPipeArgument: 'Unable to convert "giu 22, 2021 11:14:38 AM" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe'

if I try to replace giu with jun at runtime I don't get any error so the problem should be that it tries to use English instead of Italian.
I think it does not read what I defined in my app.module.ts, how to fix this?

Comment: If you look at the [source of the locale you import](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/locales/it.ts), it uses the id of 'it' and not 'it-IT'. Try changing that in your providers, I think it should fix the issue.

Comment: @TotallyNewb No, it does not work even if I change it-IT to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `toDate` is used to convert a string into the `Date` under the hood of the date pipe. Looking into [its source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/8.2.x/packages/common/src/i18n/format_date.ts#L655) I'm surprised to see the locale we provide in the module configuration is not took into account. It checks:

- if a string is actually a number (not your case)
- if a string using is in ISO format without time (not your case)
- if a string using is in ISO format with time (not your case)
- fallsback to a constructor

```js
  const date = new Date(value as any);
  if (!isDate(date)) {
    throw new Error(`Unable to convert "${value}" into a date`);
  }
  return date;
```

So, it's up to us developers to convert the date from location-specific to ISO, number or a format that we are sure would be processed by the `Date` constructor.

Comment: So basically I need to replace the first 3 char of the date string from italian to english manually and pass that string to the pipe, it's this correct?

Comment: IAfanasov Maybe a solution could be to convert the date in a different format like I tried to use numbers instead of letters for the month and the DatePipe works... But I receive the date from java call, how can I convert it to a different format? Is there any good solution that is not manual string conversion?

Comment: for now I will accept your answer since I did not found anything better, I'm trying to see if return a string from Java will get me a better solution on angular

Comment: I'm not sure about replacing the 3 char from Italian to English. If it works or not would depend on the browser's locale. I suppose the best way would be to convince BE to return ISO formatted string. If it is not possible and BE really wants to return a localized date string, I would consider sending a header with the locale identifier, so that BE would format date to a user's locale. If it's not an option, I would rather implement ad hoc date parser or use some library to convert localized date string to an object, eg https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/issues/694#issuecomment-543209946